# Entity Framework: Data size is to large. Any alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, dbset

The Enity Framework has worked great for me and I'd Like to keep it. However, one of my DbSets has 17 million records and growing quickly. Querys to that dataset take way to much time. Is there a way I can change the structure of a way to speed the querys up?

If not are there any easy alternatives to change to?

The Model is pretty Simple. I'd like to automatically split it into multiple databases by Quarter and Year since I am Only ever pulling one at a time.

```
public class Data
{
    [Key]
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Code { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }
     public int Year { get; set; }
     public int Quarter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One word: indexes.

Comment: Show the query that is taking too long to run

Comment: Assuming that the query is optimized/indexed and everything is good, sometimes EF is much slower than direct SQL. Actually I use a mixed approach where very heavy queries are done by calling a SP or SQL script and normal ones using EF.